# RelativeLayout cannot cast to TextView

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout

I have an error in which when a checkbox/row in the listview is selected, it points out to error `android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView.`

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String selectedBet = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
            if (selectedBets.contains(selectedBet)){
                selectedBets.remove(selectedBet); //uncheck
            }else{
                selectedBets.add(selectedBet);
            }
        }
    });
```

Also, here's my XML Relativelayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="75dp">

    <CheckedTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/checkmark" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I can't seem to it working, I have no idea how this works.

Comment: Can you please share you full xml layout file for better understanding.Thanks

Comment: whos your listview item layout

Comment: I cant post all of my xml file @yash786

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer given by Nilesh Rathod [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56440536/10635880) will work for you, but it's a short term solution to your problem.

Whenever you add an `OnItemClickListener` to a `ListView`, the function will always give you the root view/parent view. If you add more stuff, like a `EditText` inside the `RelativeLayout`, you'll have to find it as follows:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
        EditText editText = view.findViewById(R.id.editTextId);
        String selectedBet = textView.getText().toString();
    }
});
```

You'll have to find a particular `View` from the container layout that you'll get from `onItemClick` function, and then operate on it.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the parent layout which is a Relative Layout in your case. You have to get the CheckedTextView using it's id.